# Serious Problems with Speed and Lag continually worsening in 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed 14.04 on a clean HD. 64-bit unity. Since the computer isn't mine the specs I don't currently have on hand, but I can tell you that it shouldn't be a big problem.

The problem(s) that I have been experiencing are quite difficult to troubleshoot for, since what I am experiencing is not to my knowledge an explicit error, but rather a usability problem that worsens with each boot.

Take this particular time that I booted my computer. It took 10 minutes just to get past a blank screen with a cursor. Then I saw a second black screen, with a different font, for another 5 minutes. Then I saw the default 14.04 background. Then I waited another 10 minutes to see the login, then it crashed. So i went through the process again. You get the picture, right? Booting up takes half an hour or more.

Every other action that I want to perform or program that i want to load is similarly tedious. When I open terminal it takes about 60 seconds to see the username and computer name. My browser freezes about every 20 seconds... etc.

When I installed this new version about 2 weeks ago, the problem was slight and hardly noticable. I did my graphic design work without the slightest wink of difficulty. It has since then started causing problems and continued to worsen and now my computer is hardly usable.

Is there any way to discover what this might be? Since the problem presents itself upon first booting the computer, I doubt it has anything to do with mal-ware,spy-ware,viruses, etc. Perhaps I have the wrong install or maybe the problem is hard-ware related. How can I proceed? Should I just wipe and try a different version?

Thanks,

An Ubunt00n00b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the only OS on the machine is Ubuntu? It may be a driver issue, some bug or a hundred other things. Depending on how new your computer is(newer not always better) , try installing 12.04 on it, and see if the problem persists they are virtually identical in UI. System specs may come in useful, it may be some weird driver bug.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Thank you for answering but this answer probably should only be a comment (yes, we know you are not yet allowed to post comments) as it is mostly asking for additional information and a suggestion that - although it may circumvent the problem - does not really tackle the issue.